# remove a few items (Id) from results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

im trying to remove a few items from a query results using linqCore but its not removing them 
code& results

```
 IQueryable<int> postOn = //Results=9(Id)
                        _context.QuettaOffers.Where(d => d.SiteUserId == LoguserId).Select(s => s.QuettaReqId);

                    //Get all request that relevant to user without the one he already post on 
                    IOrderedEnumerable<QuettaReq> listOfR = //Results= 9,11 (Id) should be ..11(Id)
                        //IQueryable<QuettaReq> listOfR
                        _context.Quetta.Include(q => q.Category)
                            .Where(d => d.OfferDate > DateTime.Now && d.CatId == suplayerCat)
                            .ToList()
                            //.ToList()
                            .SkipWhile(a => a.Id.Equals(postOn))
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Id);
                    //  .TakeWhile(a => a.Id != postOn);
```

Comment: what do you mean by a few items?

Comment: try using `.SkipWhile(a => postOn.Contains(a.Id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First, `SkipWhile` / `TakeWhile` are useless for unordered sequences, which are normally the result of EF queries except they include explicit `OrderBy`. The standard and more appropriate method for filtering is `Where`.

Second, `a.Id.Equals(postOn)` resolves to `object.Equals`, and since `a.Id` is `int` and `postOn` is `IQueryable<int>`, it always evaluates to `false`.

What you really need is additional `Where` condition based on `!Contains`. It could be `&&` to the current `Where` or just separate `Where` (these constructs are treated one and the same way):

```
_context.Quetta.Include(q => q.Category)
    .Where(d => d.OfferDate > DateTime.Now && d.CatId == suplayerCat)
    .Where(q => !postOn.Contains(q.Id))
```

The additional benefit would be that the filtering will happen server side.

Comment: Thank you  for detailed explanation and create code hint

Answer (score 1):

`SkipWhile` will only skip items in the beginning of the `IEnumerable<T>.` Once that condition isn't met it will happily take the rest of the elements. Other elements that later match it down the road won't be skipped.
instead of `SkipWhile` you can use `Except`

```
var result = QueryResult.Except(a => a.Id.Equals(Id here));
```